# Create 100+ Named ranges based on formula in cells

Tags: excel, range, formula, named

been looking for quite a while now, due lack of distinctive terminology couldn't find any solution, so maybe the experts out here can help.

So I got this table of 300+ collumns that are populated like this

row 1 Header/Name.

row 2 Range formula ment to be in the "Refers to" input area when a "New Name" for a range is created.

row 3/22 The information used in the range formula.

To use the range formula's in a data validation on another sheet I need to Name these ranges. If I manually enter a "New Name" I can copy the range formula from row 2 into the "refers to" input area, only with 300 columns that would be a long day of labor. That's when I found out about the <kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> combo which makes it possible to create a lot of named ranges at once based on a header/name and selection. Unfortunately this uses the location of selection as the source and in my case it should be the formula inside the locations's cell which would have to be the source...

So is there a way to use the "Create Names From Selection" tool that uses a formula inside a cell as the source instead of the location?

here's an image to help describe the problem [image: screenshot to show problem]

Comment: Are you sure that you need 300 different named ranges for the validation? More information about the construction of the second sheet could be useful. Maybe you could solve the problem with just a single named range.

Comment: 300 could be a bit less, but has to be above 200 lines. In this document I'm creating an order form. We have around 400 products in different color combinations.

Comment: I've constructed the sheet that when a product name or code is entered it autofills the corresponding name/code, price, MOQ, and a soon to be drop down list data validation of the colors available. All the cells are dependent on the name or code entered. So when for example "product 1" is entered in row, it searches corresponding colors in another sheet, than turns those into a dynamic list which should populate the data validation. When a different product is entered in row 1 it should return those corresponding colors.

Comment: The data validation in row1 is always based on dynamic range 1, row2 dynamic range2, etc... Hope this clears things up. Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to solve this problem with 1 named range for every validation (plus 2 additional to make the formula less complicated).

The first named range (`all_headers`) should be defined as:

```
=OFFSET('C'!$A$1,0,0,1,COUNTA('C'!$1:$1))
```

It returns a range with the headers (product names or codes) from the `C` sheet. We assume that the first column is A and there are no empty columns between them.

Next we need to choose the right column. Here it gets a little tricky. In the row where you want to validate colors, you need to have exactly the same product name or code that is used in the `C` sheet headers. If this information is in cell A2, you should:

- select the cell in the same row and in the column where the color validation is supposed to be (for example B2)
- define new named range `col_header` with the following formula:

  ```
  =INDEX(all_headers,1,MATCH(A2,all_headers,0))
  ```

The above dynamic named range is **relative**, that's why selecting the proper cell before defining it is very important.

The last step is to define named range `val_list` with reference to the list of colors from the chosen column:

```
=OFFSET(col_header,2,0,COUNTA(OFFSET(col_header,2,0,50,1)),1)
```

You mentioned that the second row does not contain data, that's why there is `2` parameter twice in the formula. If you remove it, use `1` instead. `50` is the maximum number of colors - you can adjust it.

Now you can use `val_list` for validation in any cell. It should give you the right list if the cell on the left contains a valid product name/code from the `C` sheet header.

Comment: Thank you sir, I understand the flow but don't understand the Tricky Part.. http://s13.postimg.org/r55wjyn5z/Capture.png this is the FORM! sheet were the user should input the order. All the blue colloms are populated automatically and in column G is where the validation should take place. All the cells in this sheet are populated by information on sheet X! which is a import of our master product sheet containing all product names/codes and colors..

Comment: http://s16.postimg.org/i2apw99k5/Capture2.png Is what I've made out of the first part of your comment. the All_Headers range should be the first OFFSET formula based of row B$2:2 which contains the exact product codes. I've populated the All_Headers row with a link to the FORM!E column. With this information could you re-explain where I should do this?: "select the cell in the same row and in the column where the color validation is supposed to be (for example B2)" Really gratefull for your help by the way, thanks a bunch!

Comment: Your product code is in `E2` and color validation is in `G2`. So select G2 cell, then define a new named range `col_header` as `=INDEX(all_headers,1,MATCH(E2,all_headers,0))`. To test if it works as expected, you can type `=col_header` in any FORM!G cell. It should return the product code. Defining the last range should be an easy part.

Comment: Awesome! It works, this will save me a lot of work. There is just one issue remaining though. The drop down list is always populated by 20 options, which in most cases results in a lot of empty options in the dropdown list. With other words the formula doesn't exclude the blank(-looking) cells in the C!B3:Z23 table. Anyway to get some dynamic function in here to exclude the blank cells?

Comment: The reason for that and a solution is pretty simple. In `val_list` there's `COUNTA(OFFSET(col_header,2,0,50,1))`. This one counts not empty cells. Judging by your screen shot, all the cells are not empty, some of them contain empty string. Replace it with `SUMPRODUCT(--(OFFSET(col_header,2,0,50,1)<>""))`. If that works for you, please accept the answer and upvote it, so others can see it.

Comment: That doesn't work, data validation returns the following error message: "The list source must be a delimited list,or a reference to a single row or column." See attached screenshot: http://s15.postimg.org/kecf9ki0r/Capture.png

Comment: My bad, I had to add the sumproduct part, I all works perfectly now, thank you so much for all your help! Unfortunately to few reputation points to upvote your answer.